# Customization of header and footer

Tags: sql, html, file, header, customization

I have a webpage where i have to allow the users to customize their header and footer.
i.e. I should store the Users header and footer HTML and should dynamically add it to the webpage. I have two ways of storing in database and storing in a files. Please suggest me which approach is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with files get messier with time. With databases, it is easier to scale.

With databases, you can add bookkeeping fields (like last-modified, tags, or something else depending on your need). Backup is easier also perhaps.

With files, you have to worry about directory structure (having too many files in single directory is not good), permissions, etc.

If you are worried about efficiency, stop worrying :). MySQLqueries are pretty fast especially with  the caching mechanisms/modules in apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .Net you've something called Portals which does the same thing. There are things like master pages also that you may want to read. But all these are in .Net. Even if you're not doing this in .Net it'd be time consuming to handle all this stuff on your own as you need to take care of cross-site scripting and a few other issues.

Check the platform for features that you're working on to find out if this is possible by them. (Let me know the platform that you're using so I may help in that). Also, if the changes are just cosmetic you may store just css settings instead of complete html.

Finally it'd be better to use sql if the number of changes to store are more than 100 as the complexity will bug you down. But if you're fewer users and don't expect any scaling up then sure go for a file system.

:
Here are a couple of links for understanding portals and web parts in .Net:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300767.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163965.aspx

Comment: I am using .Net . My case cannot be solved with the master pages. I dont know much about the portals. can you give me some reference where i can read about the same.

Comment: Hey thanks for the references. I am anyway using the database thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ther's not a better approach (there are pro and cons in general) but in this specific case I would store these snippet as a file because you have less complexity for sure (because you don't need to query a database and fetching result) and you don't relies on database connection for including header and footer